# Excel Formula to count rows in a column when a criteria is met in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have two sheets "Aug" & "Dashboard."
The "Aug" sheet it is always growing and it has multiple columns, but the important ones are "Week" (Week is in B3) and "Group" (in C3).

I am able to do a formula that will count if any row in the "Group" column has the word "Harvest". =COUNTIF(Aug!C3:Aug!C1301,"Harvest")

But, I would also like to be able to count the number of times Harvest shows up depending on the week and to put that information in a certain cell in the "Dashboard" Sheet.

Here is what the "Aug" sheet could look like

```
Week Group 
31   harvest
31   harvest
31   rqst
31   harvest
32   harvest
32   harvest
```

The "Dashboard" sheet has a cell (A35) where you type in the week you want to look at.
For example if I want the sheet to count how many times the word harvest shows up in week 31 then I would type 31 and I should expect the number 3 to turn up.

I tried using a countif formula and an if formula, but that didn't work for me. Here is the formula that I tried using.

=IF(Dashboard!A36=Aug!B4:AugB1301, COUNTIF(Aug!C4:Aug!C1302,"Harvest"))

I get a #name! error.

I then tried focusing on just one cell to see but I can't even get that to pull correctly.

=IF(Dashboard!A36=Aug!B1302, COUNTIF(Aug!C4:Aug!C1302,"Harvest"))

So What I understand from my formula is that If the number in cell A35 matches a the cell in the Aug sheet b1302, the it should count the entire column C and count how many times the word harvest comes up. 
I keep getting a False statement.

I can make the countif statement work on it's own. I can use the count if statement to give me a total of "harvest" in the entire column.

I want it to count per the week i tell it to.

[Snippet of my Dashboard sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMQdK.png)

[Example of my Aug Sheet where I want to focus on just one cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXVwC.png)

And, if there is a VBA code that does this then it will be so much better because I will be able to have the formulas hidden.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COUNTIFS() with an `S` allows multiple criteria:

```
=COUNTIFS(Aug!C3:Aug!C1301,"Harvest",Aug!B3:Aug!B1301,Dashboard!A36)
```

Comment: So this formula will count the cells in column C if it has the word harvest, and if the cells in column B matches my cell A36?

Comment: it works! Thank you so much you are my hero :) I can't believe it was that simple.